# Can't Read Query Parameters From Promise

Tags: angular, angular-promise, query-string, angular-observable, angular-activatedroute

I am trying to read the query parameters from a URL in Angular like so:

```js
export class QueryParameterReader implements OnInit {
  constructor(private currentActiveRoute: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.currentActiveRoute.queryParams.subscribe((queryParams: Params) => {
      console.log("Recieved query parameters: " + queryParams['userid']);
    });
  }
}
```

But as soon as I try to do it through a Promise, it fails (the `then` handler never fires):

```js
export class QueryParameterReader implements OnInit {
  constructor(private currentActiveRoute: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.currentActiveRoute.queryParams.toPromise().then((queryParams: Params) => {
      console.log("Recieved query parameters: " + queryParams['userid']);
    });
  }
}
```

Any idea why this might be happening? It seems to me that I should be doing this the second way, because I want to read the query parameters only once; it doesn't make sense to keep an Observable open the whole time.

Comment: Yup, the answer to the duplicate redirect solved my problem. Although, because of the re-factoring they've done with `operators` in RxJS recently, the syntax has changed a bit.

Comment: The import statement becomes `import {first} from "rxjs/operators"` and the `toPromise()` bit becomes `this.currentActivateRoute.queryParams.pipe(first()).toPromise().then()`